# How C++ templates are a form of declarative specification, as in Prolog?

Tags: c++, prolog

On his Peter Norvig's amazing article [Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](https://www.norvig.com/21-days.html), he says the following:

> Learn at least a half dozen programming languages. Include one language that emphasizes class abstractions (like Java or C++), one that emphasizes functional abstraction (like Lisp or ML or Haskell), one that supports syntactic abstraction (like Lisp), **one that supports declarative specifications (like Prolog or C++ templates)**, and one that emphasizes parallelism (like Clojure or Go).

The bold part got my attention. I searched for and didn't find any content that connected, explicitly, C++ Templates (which I think Norvig treated here as a language because they're Turing complete), Prolog and declarative specification.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm half-good in C++ but could you please provide a Prolog example that I could use to work with to build the confidence to answer?

Comment: One could argue that pure functional languages like Haskell also support declarative specification. In fact C++ templates bear more similarity to Haskell than to Prolog.

Comment: I think declarative *specification* is supposed to mean something other than declarative programming(in haskell and functional programming sense).

Comment: Partial specialization matching rules are similar to how prolog matches things, maybe that's their point.